# Build Error Ambiguous Reference WCF

Tags: wcf

I am created a wcf service. Everything has been working fine. Now all of a sudden with adding any logic I am getting a build error where I am consuming the wcf service saying:
I have an Ambiguous Reference.

I can fix this by qualifiing the object as part of the service and it works fine

```
ServiceReference1.AccountCredit=GetSomeData()
```

The thing is all thee other objects on the page are referencing an objectModel dll except this one.

I went further and viewed the service reference itself in the browser and see visual studio for whatever reason on this particular object added a file containing the following:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <!-- 
    This file is automatically generated by Visual Studio .Net. It is 
    used to store generic object data source configuration information.  
    Renaming the file extension or editing the content of this file may   
    cause the file to be unrecognizable by the program.


  --> 
- <GenericObjectDataSource DisplayName="AccountCredit" Version="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
  <TypeInfo>TestMethods.ServiceReference1.AccountCredit, Service References.ServiceReference1.Reference.cs, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null</TypeInfo> 
  </GenericObjectDataSource>
```

All the other objects I use dont have this and in turn this is the only object on the client that is complaining.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that "MyObject" is the only name that is present in two different namespaces, where both the namespaces are referenced by a using statement at the top of the cs file.

Comment: How would I see or fix this? The code should read ServiceReference1.AccountCredit=GetSomeData() sorry